# String specification with field delimiter - with field has data

Tags: string, field, specifications

I have to format a string with 5 fields separated with field delimiter ';'.
eg.
Field1;Field2;Field3;Field4;Field5

This is the specifications:
"If there is no data for a given field, it will still have a delimiter (semi-colon) to mark its position unless there are no subsequent fields in the record that contain data.  A semi-colon will follow the last field that actually has data."

If I have Field 2 and Field 3 empty, then this will be like this:
Field1;;;Field4;Field5

My question is what if I have this condition:
Field 1, Field 2 and Field 3 have data.
Field 4 and Field 5 are empty?

Comment: what language is this in?

Comment: This is the specifications of a text file into which I have to write strings into. So it is not related to a particular programming language, may be C++ or C# by different developer. I just wanted to know what should I format the string if the last 2 fields are empty (no data).